Panda Query with Large Numeric Value Argument
I have a data frame of with a column of large numbers



A
B




1202089618
value1


12020896188572046212
value2



Assuming we have a data frame df of the above table,
df.query('A==1202089618') works to filter out the first row.
but
df.query('A==12020896188572046212') can not filter out the second row.
I am suspecting the numeric value is too large to be embedded into a query string. In this case, how to query by large numeric value?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example to help others understand your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

This is correct, the integer is too large. query is based on a C-library (numexpr) and the integer is too large to be converted to a C long (python integers can have an arbitrary length).
The error message is actually quite explicit:
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

A workaround is to use engine='python':
df.query('A == 12020896188572046212', engine='python')

Or switch to loc:
df.loc[lambda x: x['A'] == 12020896188572046212]

Output:
                      A       B
1  12020896188572046212  value2


You can achieve this goal using a mask:
df[df.A ==1202089618]
df[df.A ==12020896188572046212]
You can prove that it runs without any problem here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16cocT3SIlsJV9hl8nKcZU7kTAaPD4-dN?usp=sharing
Using query() method I was also able to do it on my machine without any problem, so I think the issue is due to pandas version.
Here is a pic where you can see the output in my machine and the pandas and python version.
